# how to stop response time and count mouse clicks

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The code below is a dynamic way of displaying each option as checkbox buttons for each question:

```
        function ExpandOptionType($option) { 
                $options = explode('-', $option);
                if(count($options) > 1) {
                    $start = array_shift($options);
                    $end = array_shift($options);
                    do {
                        $options[] = $start;
                    }while(++$start <= $end);
                 }
                 else{
                    $options = explode(' or ', $option);
                 }
                 echo '<p>';
                 foreach($options as $indivOption) {
                     echo '<div id="ck-button"><label class="fixedLabelCheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-' . $indivOption . '" value="' . $indivOption . '" /><span>' . $indivOption . '</span></label></div>';
                 }
                  echo '</p>';


            }


            foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key=>$question) {

            ?>

            <p><?php echo ExpandOptionType(htmlspecialchars($arrOptionType[$key])); ?></p>

    <p><input type='text' class='questionIds' name='questionids' value='<?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionId[$key]); ?>' /></p>

    <p><input type='text' class='responseTime' name='responsetime' value='00:00:00' /></p>

    <p><input type='text' class='mouseClick' name='mouseclick' value='0' /></p>

}
```

Now below I 2 text inputs which are also in the foreach loop, one for response time and other is for counting mouse click:

```
<p><input type='text' class='responseTime' name='responsetime' value='00:00:00' /></p>

<p><input type='text' class='mouseClick' name='mouseclick' value='0' /></p>
```

Now this is my questions:

1. The response time text input contains a count up timer. What I want is that if the first button checkbox is clicked in a question, the question's response timer should stop. This is so we know how long it took the user to respond answering a particular question
2. The mouse click text starts with 0 and what I want this text input to do is for every button checkbox that is clicked in a question, the question's mouse click text input counts up the amount of clicks so we know how many clicks on the question's options the user has compiled.

How can the above be achieved?

Below is a jsfiddle showing sample code of what it looks like for one question:

http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/630/

UPDATE:

Source code showing multiple questions example:

```
QUESTION 1:

<p>
<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-A" value="A" />
<span>A</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-B" value="B" />
<span>B</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-C" value="C" />
<span>C</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-D" value="D" />
<span>D</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-E" value="E" />
<span>E</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-F" value="F" />
<span>F</span>
</label>
</div>

</p>

<p><input type='text' class='questionIds' name='questionids' value='73' /></p>


<p><input type='text' class='responseTime' name='responsetime' value='00:00:00' /></p>

<p><input type='text' class='mouseClick' name='mouseclick' value='0' /></p>



QUESTION 2:

<p>
<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-A" value="A" />
<span>A</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-B" value="B" />
<span>B</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-C" value="C" />
<span>C</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-D" value="D" />
<span>D</span>
</label>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
<label class="fixedLabelCheckbox">
<input type="checkbox" name="options[]" id="option-E" value="E" />
<span>E</span>
</label>
</div>

</p>

<p><input type='text' class='questionIds' name='questionids' value='74' /></p>


<p><input type='text' class='responseTime' name='responsetime' value='00:00:00' /></p>

<p><input type='text' class='mouseClick' name='mouseclick' value='0' /></p>
```

Comment: the timer is for the user also ? if not cache $.now() on checkbox click, then on the next one $.now()- the cached one & put that value to a hidden input next to the question that was answered; code would be way simpler

Comment: @mikakun The text inputs will be changed into hidden inputs, I just placed it as text inputs so I can see the values to know what is happening.

Comment: so use $.now() on checkbox click & form submit (for the last one); make a global array for your clicks with one index for each question that you increment upon click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you created a reference for setinterval that is good. Now you can remove the set interval on click event  of first checkbox and add a click event on all checkbox to increase counter.

That will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var checkBox=$('#ck-button').find('input');
var responsetimer=//your interval function
checkbox.filter(':first').bind('click',function(e){
 clearInterval(responsetimer);
});
checkbox.bind('click',function(e){
$('.mouseClick').val(parseInt($('.mouseClick').val())+1);
});
});
```

Well i am not sure about the question you want timer to be stopped at first button click or first time button clicked. If it is first time than dont use the first binding . keep clear interval in second binding itself.

```
checkbox.bind('click',function(e){
 clearInterval(responsetimer);
 $('.mouseClick').val(parseInt($('.mouseClick').val())+1);
});
```

JS fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/631/
for second option
http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/638/

**UPDATE**
if you want this for multiple question wrap each question with a div say `<div class="queWrap"></div>`

Make a array refrence for your interval function so that it can be clear.

Loop to each queWrap and start timer and assign events on checkbox.

Check example for multiple question :http://jsfiddle.net/zAFND/640/

Comment: Hi, only issue is the timer does not stop after first click on a checkbox button

Comment: Does your fiddle match the second option? It is first time a button is clicked for each question, so question 1, I click on a checkbox button, timer for question 1 stops, for question 2, click on checkbox button in question 2 and question 2 timer stops etc. Did you change html btw?

Comment: In your fiddle there was only one question. If it is for multiple question you need to create different textbox for each question. Do no of click textbox will be one for all questions?

Comment: Each question has its own response time text box and mouse click text box. So really final thing to do is get it working for multiple questions and you have cracked it. We can see it works in fiddle, just not working in app but thats becuse my app has multiple questions

Comment: I included under update section source code of example of multiple questions looks like, if you look at first code snippet in question, it shows the php code which creates the multiple questions and its features

Comment: Little issue with timer going up by 2 seconds but I will figure that out. Thank you :) +1, best answer